# similarity and difference using the Post and Message in Handler ( Multi-Threading in android)

Tags: android, multithreading, post, handler, message

```
<blink>
   Please help me!
```

"Similarity and difference using the Post and Message in Handler (MultiThreading in android)".

Comment: didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should go with following. 
1. [Multithreading in android](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html)
2. [Multi threading with Handler Class](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-multi-threading-in-android-with-handler-class/28175)
3. [Process and Threads in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
4. [Handler in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)